# Setting CSS backgroundImage path in Javascript with ERB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying to set the background image of an element using erb in a javascript file

```
document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>";
```

But the image doesn't show.

When I inspect the element on the browser and visit the url produced for the image, the image appears.

When I change `backgroundImage` to `backgroundColor = "red"`, it works.

So if the path is right, and the js for styling the element works, what is the problem ?

Comment: @OhHendrie I'd delete that comment if I were u

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Nowhere in that guide does it say to use ERB in a javascript file. Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Read it and return plz

Comment: You can absolutely use ERB in a JS view file for a rendered JS.

Comment: I just don't think you should need to.

Comment: @davidhoelzer any ideas on my problem?

Comment: Why would you not use css to set the background image?

Comment: @shiva I don't have the time to google it but I seemed to remember needing to do:  `backgroundImage: url('<%=...%>')`

Comment: @shiva Also, make sure you are forcing a full refresh when testing.  Javascript is notorious for getting cached in the browser and creating development troubleshooting nightmares if you forget to force the refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't work because it's not the right syntax, you are missing the `url` part!

```
document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url(<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>)";
```

This should do the trick ;)

However, why do you use javascript to do something like this and not CSS?

Comment: Thanks. This is just one line within a bigger function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use css to do this.

```
.logo {
  background-image: '/assets/images/logo.png'
}
```

As an alternative, you can use obtrusive Javascript in layout or page erb file: include  tags and use ruby embedded code.